# Sync video to audio bpm

Tags: video, playback

Hi what I want to do is play a music playlist and then vary the playback speed of a video file based on the current music tempo.

Basically its for indoor cycling, running I want to vary the speed of the scenery based on the music tempo.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, nor know how it works, but I've read interesting stories about [xjadeo](http://xjadeo.sourceforge.net/) (used with jack audio)